# Creating irregular shaped JavaFX component

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to make an irregular shaped component for JavaFX, and experience very odd behavior.

```
package pkg;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;

public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        for (int x = 50; x < 150; x += 50) {
            for (int y = 50; y < 150; y += 50) {
                pane.getChildren().add(new Triangle(x, y));
            }
        }
        scene = new Scene(pane, 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    private static class Triangle extends Region {

        Polygon p;

        public Triangle(int x, int y) {
            super();
            p = new Polygon(x - 25, y + 25, x, y - 25, x + 25, y + 25);
            setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                    p.setFill(Color.RED);
                    System.out.println("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
                }
            });
            setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                    p.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                }
            });
            setShape(p);
            getChildren().add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>15.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When this is run, it creates 4 Triangles, each with a mouseover behavior.

However, when you mouseover each triangle, they all act as if the lower right triangle is being triggered.

This is not intuitive. I don't know quite what is doing that.

What is happening here, and how do I make these components react independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the region's bounds will start at `[0,0]` and extend to fill the space required by all children. Thus the last triangle you create actually has bounds covering all the others, and since it is top-most in the stack (because you add it last), it receives all mouse events.

If you push each triangle to the back (which isn't a particularly good solution), you see what you want:

```
    for (int x = 50; x < 150; x += 50) {
        for (int y = 50; y < 150; y += 50) {
            Triangle t = new Triangle(x, y);
            pane.getChildren().add(t);
            t.toBack();
        }
    }
```

Another solution is to add

```
setPickOnBounds(false) ;
```

to the `Triangle` constructor. This will only trigger mouse events if the mouse is over a non-transparent part of the `Triangle`.

Probably though you should be creating regions which only occupy the space they really need. You likely also want the `setPickOnBounds(false)` call, so the triangle only responds to a mouse being over the triangular part (not the full rectangular area containing it):

```
private static class Triangle extends Region {

    Polygon p;

    public Triangle() {
        super();
        p = new Polygon(0, 50, 25, 0, 50, 50);
        setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                p.setFill(Color.RED);
            }
        });
        setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                p.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            }
        });
        setShape(p);
        getChildren().add(p);
        setPickOnBounds(false);
    }
}
```

And then you can lay the triangles out in their containing pane in the usual way:

```
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    for (int x = 25; x < 125; x += 50) {
        for (int y = 25; y < 125; y += 50) {
            Triangle t = new Triangle();
            pane.getChildren().add(t);
            t.setLayoutX(x);
            t.setLayoutY(y);
        }
    }
```

They will also work with layout panes:

```
    GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
            Triangle t = new Triangle();
            pane.add(t, x, y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked a treat. I did not realize the hover activity was happening on the white space in my test, I thought it was happening on the other triangles.